# Run geotools on web server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, applet, geotools

I am trying run geotools on the web with postgis database and have been searching around how to run geotools in Java. What i found is geotools with applets.

Does anyone know what is the best way to get geotools run on the web server. Is it possible to run geotools with servlet. Am new to this, so excuse some "java notions" mistake.
Thanks

Comment: just like any other java lib - see geoserver.org for a full example

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at geoserver ? It's core is geotools.